# android Firebase Appliaction Stopped

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

when i run my application to upload an image from an external storage to firebase cloud storage application has been stopped after pressing the upload button.

```
    FS = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    Ref = FS.getReference("Record_Unknown/");
    Updata = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Updata_btn);

    Updata.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override

    public void onClick(View v) {
    InputStream inputStream = null;
        try {
            inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(getFilesDir(),"view-of-mountain-under-blue-sky-2104147.jpg"));
        }catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    UploadTask uploadTask = Ref.child("Images/view-of-mountain-under-blue-sky-2104147.jpg").putStream(inputStream);
        final InputStream finalInputStream = inputStream;
        uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                if (finalInputStream !=null){
                    try {
                        finalInputStream.close();
                    }
                    catch (IOException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Uploaded Sucessfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

    }
});}
```

[image]

*line no.94 is given below:*

```
                inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(getFilesDir(),"view-of-mountain-under-blue-sky-2104147.jpg"));
```

*line no.100 is given below:*

```
        UploadTask uploadTask = Ref.child("Images/view-of-mountain-under-blue-sky-2104147.jpg").putStream(inputStream);
```

Comment: the image is not found

Answer (score 1):

As the exception you show says the file you are trying to load does not exist.

The getFilesDir() in android returns the application storage directory which is private to your application (and not visible to a file browser on the device). If you are trying to access the shared part of the file system you need:
a) Priviledges
b) To use another call to get the relevant part of the file system

Android docs summarise the available areas here https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage